# How can I recognize different applications in NetFlow dumps?

Tags: facebook, reverse-dns, netflow

I try to discover what kind of applications work in my network (e.g. Facebook, Youtube, Twitter etc.) . Unfortunatelly I can't do Deep Packet Inspection, everything I have are NetFlow traces. I was thinking about resolving ip addresses using DNS server and check domain names of flows. But what if application use domain that doesn't contain app name? Is that any possibility to find all ip addresses that use specific app/website?

Answer (score 0):

Outside deep packet inspection (in which I include tech like Cisco NBAR) your main tools are probably going to be whois and port/protocol pair. Some commercial NetFlow collectors will do some of the legwork for you, for example by doing autonomous system lookup on incoming IP addresses, or providing the IANA protocol list.

The term "application" is a bit overloaded in this domain, by the way: often it's used to mean HTTP, SSH, POP3 and similar protocols in the OSI Application Layer, which are generally guessed from the port/protocol pair. For Facebook, Hotmail, etc, the whois protocol is probably your best bet. It's a bit better than reverse DNS, but the return formats aren't standardized among the Regional Internet Registries, so your parser is going to need to have some smarts. Get the IP addresses for a few of the major sites and use the command line `whois` utility with them to get a feel for the output before scripting anything.

Fortunately, most of the big ones are handled by ARIN. Look for "NetName" and "OrgName" in the results (and watch for the RIR names (RIPE, APNIC, etc) to indicate where that IP address isn't handled by ARIN). For example, I see `www.stackoverflow.com` as `198.252.206.16`. `whois 198.252.206.16` returns (among other things,

```
 NetName:        SE-NET01
 OrgName:        Stack Exchange, Inc.
```

You didn't specify whether you were shell scripting or programming; if the latter, the WHOIS protocol is standard and has a number of implementations in most languages.